# query error: no field 'face' found in schema

Tags: sphinx

i have bigint column named as face in mysql. and this is my sphinx.conf

```
source src1
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = pass
    sql_db          = nums
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = SELECT id,id AS id_attr,tel,name,sex,face from tel
    sql_attr_uint   = id_attr
    sql_attr_bigint = face
}

index num
{
    rt_attr_bigint  = face
    rt_field = face
    source          = src1
    path            = C:/sphinx/bin/data/numaralar
}
```

i can make search by name and tel but not with face.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Foolz\SphinxQL\Exception\DatabaseException' with message '[1064] index nums: query error: no field 'face' found in schema [ SELECT * FROM nums WHERE MATCH('(@face 123456)') LIMIT 0, 10 OPTION max_matches = 5000;SHOW META]' in ..

why may it be?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the value as an **field**. The @ fulltext operator (and indeed the whole of MATCH() full text query, operates on fields ONLY.

You've instead defined `face` as an **atribute**. Attributes don't work in full-text queries.

Can

1. Make `face` a **field** *instead* (remove the `sql_attr_bigint`) or make it *both* an attribute and field. (to do that, would have to duplicate it like you've duplicated the id, one for field, one for attribute. or use `sql_field_string`, but that makes a string attribute)

or

2. Use filter by the attribute instead. Dont really know how to do that in Foolz. But the SphinxQL query would be something like

---

```
SELECT * FROM nums WHERE `face` = 123456 LIMIT 0, 10
```